# How many compositions of $n$ into distinct $k$ parts are there

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $n, k$ be a non-negative integers with $k\leq n$. A $k$-composition or a composition of $n$ into $k$ parts is a $k$-tuple $(x_1, ..., x_k)$ such that $x_1+x_2+...+x_k = n$. I know that the number of $k$-compositions of $n$ is given by $n-1 \choose k-1$ but I'm struggling with the adding condition that the parts (the $x_i$) must be distinct. That is I want to count the number of $k$-compositions $(x_1, ..., x_k)$ of $n$ where $x_i \neq x_j$ for all $i\neq j$.

I'm also curious about this question where $(x_1, ..., x_k)\in \mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a prime and $n<p$? I feel like there should be a simple solution or bijection for both of these problems but I'm having trouble with coming up with one.

Comment: The number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ distinct positive parts is $k!$ times the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct positive parts, which is $k!$ times the number of partitions of $n-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ into $k$ positive parts, i.e.  $k!$ times the number of partitions of $n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ into up to $k$ parts or $k!$ times the number of partitions of $n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ with no part greater than $k$.  These restricted partitions are well known such as [OEIS A026820](http://oeis.org/A026820)

Comment: @Henry what about solutions in finite fields? Is this also well-known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question was answered in the comments.

In the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p$ prime, if $k > p$ then there are no choices of $k$ distinct elements. If $k = p$, then there is a unique choice, so up to reordering there is a unique solution if $n \equiv p(p-1)/2$ and none otherwise. So given $n < p$ and considering all orderings, there are $p!$ solutions if $p$ odd and $n = 0$, $2$ solutions if $p = 2$ and $n = 1$ and $0$ solutions otherwise.

If $k < p$, then the number of solutions is the same for every $n$, since adding $k^{-1}$ to every $x_i$ adds $1$ to $n$ and is a bijection on the set of solutions. As $n$ varies from over $0, \dotsc, p-1$, there are a total of $\binom{p}{k} k!$ solutions, so the number of solutions for a fixed $n < p$ is $\frac1p \binom{p}{k} k! = \frac{(p-1)!}{(p-k)!}$.